# java logical error in String operation

Tags: java

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String A=sc.next();
String B=sc.next();
System.out.println(A.length()+B.length());       

int x=(new Character(A.charAt(0)).toString()).compareToIgnoreCase(new Character(B.charAt(0)).toString());        

if(x>0){System.out.println("Yes");}

else {System.out.println("No");}


String a=A.replace(new Character(A.charAt(0)).toString(),new Character(A.charAt(0)).toString().toUpperCase()); 

String b=B.replace(new Character(B.charAt(0)).toString(),new Character(B.charAt(0)).toString().toUpperCase()); 
System.out.println(a+" "+b);
```

What is the problem when I enter aa & a as two inputs A&B necessary output is not revieved. 3rd line printed must be Aa A. But this prints as AA A. Any thoughts about why??

Comment: Why you're creating so many objects?

Comment: because it does replace every `a` with `A`. That´s what `String#replace` is supposed to do, replace every occurence. If you only want to replace the first occurence you might want to work with `String#replaceAll` and regex.

Comment: i guess you can add a print statement between String A=sc.next();
    String B=sc.next();, then you know why

Comment: thanks a lot.. I am novice to java...that's why. I'll try with substring method

Comment: Hint: one part of learning java is to learn the APIs. If you are using methods on String, Character, ... then **first** read the javadoc to understand what is going on. Besides: your code looks extremely ... over complicated. What is it actually supposed to do?

Comment: it's supposed to output the length of the sum of two strings, check which word comes first alphabatically and finally make first letter of two strings uppercase and then join them. Anyway thank for the tip...

Answer (score 0):

The `replace(old,new)` function of `String` replaces ALL occurences of `old` by `new`, hence you get AA A.

Try using the `replaceFirst(old,new)` function of `String` instead:

```
String firstA = new Character(A.charAt(0)).toString();
String a = A.replaceFirst(firstA, firstA.toUpperCase());

String firstB = new Character(B.charAt(0)).toString();
String b = B.replaceFirst(firstB, firstB.toUpperCase());
```